# @html.PasswordFor display text

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to have a @html.PasswordFor control that has display text of black dots (discs) that doesn't have any value so doesn't save anything to the database when clicking save?

I want to be able to show the user that there is a password there but if they don't make any changes to it, it will remain the same. Can I do this without having to load the passwords on page load?

Here is an example of what I want to show. (I know it is showing stars but if possible I want to have black discs the same that normally shows in this control). The example below will actually save the value ******* to the database but I don't want this to happen unless they edit the control then all the ****** need to disappear so that they don't get added to the users password.

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @Value = "********"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill it in with a dummy value in your view model. Have a hidden input that is set to a boolean value. Once the password input is changed, changed the hidden input value to true. Then in your controller, inspect the boolean value and if it meets your condition, set the password.